# Does the WKWebView support websocket?

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, websocket, uiwebview

I have very short question. I'm starting to develop an app, which is targeted to Android, but why not try to use it on iOS? Application has WebView only and it will use WebSocket for communication.

My question is, does the UIWebView support WebSocket or is it necessary to use external libraries? I don't have an Apple device to check and didn't find any information in the internet.

Thanks for any hint.

EDIT:I've read that UIWebView is deprecated. What about WKWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that WKWebView does support Web Sockets. What really surprised me is it also supports keeping the websockets open in the background (assuming you have the appropriate requirements set up in your app). You can then pass messages to the native side as required using the `messageHandlers.postMessage` mechanism.

Alternatively if you wanted to take a more native approach you could use SocketRocket which is a library developed by Facebook

Comment: What requirements in the app are you referring to? I have not been able to keep a socket connection open when the app enters the background (the socket connection is through a WKWebView).

Comment: @timgcarlson its been a long time since I looked at this, but if you head to your target settings and click on the `signing & capabilities` tab, click on `+ Capability` and search for something like "Background Modes" That should point you in the right direction

Comment: @timgcarlson did you find something out?