# WKWebView: [ProcessSuspension] - TimedActivity::activityTimedOut:

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using a `WKWebView` to load a page, but after might be 5 minutes I got:

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x7fded682fec8 - TimedActivity::activityTimedOut:
2021-07-06 15:20:32.751176+0800 ATP Demo2[15923:9181871] [ProcessSuspension] 0x7fded68dd6c8 - TimedActivity::activityTimedOut:
2021-07-06 15:20:33.020953+0800 ATP Demo2[15923:9181871] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

These two methods in `WKNavigationDelegate` are not be called.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        fatalError("didFailProvisionalNavigation")

    }
```

Seems there's a `activityTimedOut` happened. Any way to catch this error and reload the web view?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this is not crashing the app. It is just a message in the XCode console. That's right?

Comment: @Starsky yes, not crash the app. For some reason my webpage should keep getting data but after few minutes it gets no response and this message comes out. So guess could be the reason not for sure.

Comment: Maybe you didn't use WKWebViews in a while, but these console warnings are a natural thing since XCode 11 I guess. These messages just appear, they are annoying, but they don't really cause any interruptions. Some people recommend to just ignore these messages.

Comment: OK, `Maybe you didn't use WKWebViews in a while` do you know any way to make `WKWebViews` active is isn't used for a while?

Comment: I am sorry, what I meant, is that I assumed you didn't use WKWebViews in your iOS development for a while, otherwise you would've noticed earlier that these warnings in XCode console are a natural thing when working with WKWebViews. In your case, maybe a `WKWebview.reload()` might be a solution, although I guess it will flicker while reloading. Can you explain what are you doing with the webView for 5 minutes? Is it a video app? What happens exactly after 5 minutes which bothers you?

Comment: np, got it. Actually there's an endless GET request with the body keep inserting tags like <script> xxx </script> and I need to keep parsing the data. All works fine just after 5-10 minutes or even longer. All the data won't be updated. I tried URLSession, but not sure why I lost some data some times.

Comment: "an endless GET request" sounds not very good, to be honest ))) You might want to look into Sockets. Maybe this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49276145/8314394) will be a good starting point. Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks, it's legacy issue. I totally agree. thanks any way.